# Android Canvas drawcolor throws Null pointer exception

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, render, android-canvas

Developing a small Android game (2.1 till 4.2 support), Below code often throws java.lang.NullPointerException exception at

***canvas.drawColor((0xFFAAAAAA);***

```
public class MainGamePanel extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

public void render(Canvas canvas) {             

        canvas.drawColor(0xFFAAAAAA);   

        droid.draw(canvas);

    }
}
```

Here is the stack trace

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.rdx.play.MainGamePanel.render(MainGamePanel.java:186)
at com.rdx.play.MainThread.run(MainThread.java:54)
```

The exception is inconsistent, what might be causing this issue?

Many Thanks.

Comment: `drawColor((` is a typo right? Also, since you know that `canvas` is `null` at times, why not debug the code and see which call to `render` sends a `null` as an argument.

Comment: corrected the typo, the crash is visible on 4.0 , but never on 2.3 and 2.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SurfaceHolder.lockCanvas()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceHolder.html#lockCanvas%28%29) is allowed to return null (cos your thread doesn't have exactly the same lifetime as the surface). I bet you aren't handling that possibility in your thread function.